# Apache CustomLog to log full URL

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, logging, httpd, host

I'd like to add a `CustomLog` directive to my apache configuration to log the full URL requested (or at least the host portion of the URL). I have several domains being handled by the same instance of apache, and would like to be able to distinguish the domains in the logs (as now all I see is "GET /"). I see in [the documentation on LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) it lists `%U` to print the path portion of the URL, but I'm looking for the host.

Comment: `LogFormat "%{REQUEST_SCHEME}x://%{Host}i:%p%U%q" log` does what you want

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Keep reading the `LogFormat` documentation and you'll find:

```
%...{Foobar}i:  The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the request
                sent to the server.
```

Which means you could include in your configuration:

```
%{Host}i
```

The `%v` and `%V` directives may also get you what you want.

%v will always be the value of `ServerName` (the "canonical name" of your virtual host).  `%V` *may* be the value of `ServerName`, or it may be the value of the HTTP `Host` header, depending on whether or not you have `UseCanonicalName` enabled in your configuration (and whether or not the client supplied a `Host` header).

Comment: Will `%{Host}i` work even for HTTP/1.0? `%V` looks right at first glance, thanks!

Comment: I believe that %{Host}i (or any %{...}i construct) will only produce a result if that header actually exists in the request.  So for HTTP/1.0, I would not expect it to be useful.

Comment: One more clarification: So `%V` will be identical to `%{Host}i` if `UseCanonicalName` is disabled?

Comment: According to the documentation, "With UseCanonicalName off Apache will form self-referential URLs using the hostname and port supplied by the client if any are supplied (otherwise it will use the canonical name, as defined above)."  So `%V` will use `ServerName` if there is no `Host` header.

Answer (score 3):

> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %{Host}i%U%q" combined

`%{Host}i%U%q`gives full url.

Comment: Pity that the %{Host}i%U%q ( or %{Host}i%<U%<q ) gives the full URL after all rewrites and not the original request from user.
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64117

Answer (score 2):

'%v' is the ServerName might be what you want?

Comment: It looks like `%v` always returns the same string in my situation: the ServerName value regardless of what domain appears in the URL. But `%V` looks like it does the right thing.

Comment: That is related to the virtualhost name

Answer (score 2):

Add `%v` to your log format.

Something like this:

```
LogFormat "%v - %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined-vhost
CustomLog /log/file/location combined-vhost
```

Comment: It looks like `%v` always returns the same string in my situation: the ServerName value regardless of what domain appears in the URL. But `%V` looks like it does the right thing.